# Unexpected behavior from Angular directive

Tags: angularjs

I have a page that renders about 100 dates using Angular directive. On the page load I have a list of dates that I go through each and rendering them using a directive, which sends a request to server to grab that particular date with some modification.

The problem I am facing is not always all the dates will be populated. And by refreshing the page they become populated and some other disappear, the behavior is random.

```
.directive('dname',function (service) {
    return{
        scope:{
            date:'@',
            locale:'@',
            timeZone:'@',
            format:'@',
            airport:'@',
            time:'@'
        },
        template:"<span>{{value}}</span>",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var cb = function(localeTime){
                scope.value = localeTime.formatted;
            };


            scope.$watchCollection (['date','locale','airport','timeZone','time'], function(){
                var mode = (scope.date) ? "date" : (scope.time) ? "time" : "error";
                service.processDate(mode,"",attrs,cb);

            } )
        }
    }
})
```

service.processDate is where I do some check and call the DateGenerator.get function.

I am pretty sure as far as the functionality as all my unit test are passing, no error on console and refreshing will bring the result back, but not sure how to trace this random behavior. And sometimes is fully populated.

1. Browser: chrome
2. Angular 1.1.5

UPDATE:

I was able to fix this problem, starting with @charlietfl comment regarding defining scope for each directive. After creating isolated scope, assigned a model to each one of the date directives resolved the issue.

```
<span   nj-localization  value="date['airport-'+$index]" time='2013-10-11T00:00Z' format='medium' airport='UUWW' timeZone='airport' />
```

Comment: where are you assigning response to a scope object?

Comment: @charlietfl  I am not assigning anything to my scope, as setting the element html is showing my result on the span tag. Should I change this approach ?

Comment: that could be issue, digest cycles don't know about added html. Try assigning response to scope and using expression in markup

Comment: @charlietfl I added the scope, and feel its a bit better now since its totally random, however, I still have those missing dates.

Comment: create a demo in plunker that replicates issue. Could make request to a single json file each time. Also, curious if you can't use UTC time and do conversions in javascript

Comment: @charlietfl  the service tries to convert it using moment, but for some timezones, and those that we dont have timezones will send it to back end to calculate it based on daylight saving and other parameters stored in db.

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for your suggestion. It gave me a clue to resolve it. I updated my post. Please post your suggestion as answer.

Comment: once **...the scope knows...**  the DOM takes care of itself...lol